# How to close large Javascript Alert windows on Chrome/ OSX

Tags: macos, google-chrome, javascript, osx-leopard

I'm using Chrome 14 and OSX 10.5.8.

If a website generates a Javascript alert window with a lot of content (like debug information) the bottom of the window disappears off the screen.

This places the buttons out of reach and means there is no way of closing the alert window as the "traffic light" of window buttons doesn't appear in the top left-hand corner.

Having the alert window open disables various actions on Chrome and makes it unusable. The only way I've been able to close the alert window is using "Force Quit" to close Chrome down totally.

Is there anyway of closing a Chrome Javascript alert window that is too big for screen in OSX?

Comment: you can't just hit enter?? generally on an alert the 'ok' has focus by default. i'm not sure about OSX, i'm a windows guy.

Comment: Why would you use `alert` for debug info? Use `console.log` - the console was made for debugging.

Comment: Zirak - this is how Silverstripe CMS uses alert boxes for some of it's debugging.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@rlemon has got it – activate the alert window and hit Enter. Chrome and Safari on OS X display JavaScript alert boxes with just one button (“OK” by default), which is focused.

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting dialogs which keep looping, you can click the *Prevent this page from creating additional dialogs* check box via keyboard using this sequence (with alert focused)

<kbd>Tab</kbd>, <kbd>Tab</kbd>, <kbd>Spacebar</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image]

This checkbox setting is reset per session according to [this answer by](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22544347/80428) by @dentaku.

Comment: @DavidRicherby this is actually a good answer for when there's recurring dialogs. I've explained it a little more.